# Header is not fixed when textfield onfocus event fired in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, cordova

Header is moving up/down when textfield onfocus event fired in jquery even if i used data-position="fixed" for header. Can anyone help how to fix the header when onfocus and onblur is calling?

Here is the html code.

I need to scroll list view  to upside then i click on the right button on header, one popup will come. If i select the textfiled on that popup keypad will comeup and header will move to down like below screen shot.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" style="background: rgb(25,7,7); position:absolute;left:0px;height:100%;width:320px;background-repeat:no-repeat">
    <div data-role="header"  id="page1Header" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed" style="height:46px;background:rgb(25,7,7);top:-1px">
        <img src="Images/add_btn@2x.png" id="addCategory" class="muncul"  style="position:fixed;height:25px;width:25px;right:10px;top:7px;"/>
    </div>
    <div  data-role="content" >
          <ul data-role="listview"  id="listTable" class="mainList" style="border:none;margin-top:-15px"></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="target" data-position="fixed" data-scroll="false" style="background: url(Images/popup_bg.png) no-repeat;background-size: 167px 91px;margin-left:5px">
         <input type="text"  id="adddescriptionName"  placeholder="Enter Category Name"  style="background:rgba(218,218,218,1);height:32px;width:153px;margin-top:15px;border-radius: 3px;" />
         <img  id="addSaveButton" src="Images/save_btn@2x.png" style="width:154px;background-size: 154px 29px;margin-top:1px;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Where can we see this in action?

Comment: can u add any screen shots or some example or share ur header css and textfield css styles

Comment: @hexafraction, so we won't be able to help if the questioner provides more details? You may have inverted your boolean expression here.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Bah, my stupidity again.

Answer (score -1):

You can try by making the position of the header to absolute instead of fixed.

```
#page1Header{
position:absolute !important;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

Comment: If i use absolute, header is also scrolling up with listview when i scroll list view.